# Android Facebook Login issue?

Tags: android, facebook

In my application (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cabot.beastly&feature=search_result), I am using facebook-android api to login and share to Facebook. It's works fine in emulator and Samsung Galaxy Tab when i tested. But some bugs are reporting by the client, facebook login doesn't load.

After lot of testing i found the reason. When the Facebook-Android application installed in the device the login doesn't work. Otherwise it's works fine.

```
mFacebook = new Facebook(GlobalHandler.getFacebookAppID());
mFacebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"},new LoginDialogListener());
```

How can i solve this?.

Comment: Hello i am facing the same problem in facebook and you are right even i m facing this problem while running with Android device 2.1. I think there should be some problem with oAuth and Android 2.1. As because when i try to make login with twitter through inbuilt browser, it doesn't work but as soon as i do the same task with opera mini, it works fine. I have reported the same problem couple of days ago, here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524354/facebook-login-problem-after-upgrading-to-platform-2-1-update1-and-using-officia)

Comment: I downloaded and tried ur application, ur twitter as well not working with my device which runs on 2.1update1. Please let me know if you get any solution for this.

Comment: What went wrong with twitter? Thanks for the support.

Comment: Hi i am also getting this problem. In my 2.2 device it is working well and good. But some of my client saying that face book login not happening. What's the exact solution?

Comment: Ms: Actually i found a solution of my twitter problem, i made some changes at twitter side in my application settings like, mentioned callback url and changed application type to browser and opened twitter url in Webview. This solution worked for me, as before i was just opening browser and asking user to read and write pin manually but twitter was giving me an error "Login Failed: The server failed to communicate. Try again later.". I think this is due to oAuth or else i don't know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mFacebook = new Facebook(GlobalHandler.getFacebookAppID());
mFacebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"},-1,new LoginDialogListener());
```

I changed the code, to do a forced login to facebook each time. By adding corresponding argument in the authorize function Facebook Object.

Comment: i tried but still that problem persists in my case.. please do tel me if u get any solution.

Comment: my case it's working with above code. What is ur actual problem?.

Comment: Facebook log in is not working in my case but lemme tel u Android 2.1update1 is being used by me.. Please lemme know, if u get any solution for this..

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you've not put in the correct Hash Key in the Facebook settings for Android. Use the command I have given below to generate your Key Hash, just replace the alias and keystore with your release ones. Put that Key Hash in your Facebook App settings and it will start working.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an Error:

```
"please try again: com.facebook.android. DialogError: 
the server failed to communicate.  Try again later"
```

I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S2 and trying to use facebook's com.facebook api and I was able to fix it by rebooting the smartphone.